# ¿Estoy aplicando mal la función .charAt()?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando asignarle un carácter de una cadena a un espacio concreto de otra.

Al poner lo siguiente:

```
cad2.charAt(j) = caracter;
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> *'The left-hand side of an assigment must be a variable'*

Os dejo el código del método completo para que le echéis un vistazo:

```
static String completar_cad(String cad) {
        
        String cad2="00000000";
        
        Character caracter;
        
        int j=cad2.length();
        
        for(int i=cad.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
            
            j--;
            
            caracter=cad.charAt(i);
            
            cad2.charAt(j)=caracter;
            
        }
        
    }
```

He intentado cambiar todos los apartados de la expresión y no llego a ningún puerto.

Comment: @alo Leyendo la pregunta que colocas como duplicada, y sus respuestas, queda claro que no lo es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`charAt` es una función que te devuelve un carácter de una cadena, pero **no es el caracter en si**. El compilador te está diciendo eso. Solo puedes hacer asignaciones a variables, y el resultado de una función no es una variable.

Como regla general, siempre que utilizas el operador de asignación `=`, al lado izquierdo tiene que haber una variable.

Para cambiar un carácter de una cadena tenes dos opciones,

- crear otra cadena concatenando las partes que te interesan de la cadena original, o
- utilizar un StringBuilder, que es una clase especializada en construir cadenas.

Primero, ejemplos de ambos casos para sustituir un carácter:

Médoto 1: Concatenar:

```
String myName = "domanokz";
String newName = myName.substring(0,4)+'x'+myName.substring(5);
System.out.println(newName);
```

Método 2: StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder("domanokz");
myName.setCharAt(4, 'x');
System.out.println(myName);
```

En tu caso, me parece que el método 2 se va a adaptar más fácilmente, por ejemplo:

```
static String completar_cad(String cad) {
    StringBuilder cad2 = new StringBuilder("00000000");
    Character caracter;
    int j=cad2.length();
    for(int i=cad.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        j--;
        caracter=cad.charAt(i);
        cad2.setCharAt(j)=caracter;
    }
    return(cad2.toString());
}
```

Comment: Gracias por su aportación jachguate¡ Me ha solucionado el problema¡ Un saludo¡